# Adding security to PHP mail file

Tags: php, html-email

I've created a working contact form with a PHP file. I have read so many post about security, to the point I'm really confused about what code is needed to filter out potential spammers. Code below is what I have so far. Would you be so kind as to provide any code that would secure this php file so I can learn the correct way.

---

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Call Back: $call \n Website: $website \n        Priority: $priority \n Type: $type \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "";
$subject = "Contact Form Enquiry";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.fashionablefondants.co.uk/response.html');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

Comment: Hello my emailaddress is `PeeHaa@php.net\r\nHeader: Injection`.

Comment: @PeeHaa that leak is closed though, isn't it?

Comment: @Pekka웃 How? `$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";`. I.e. `"From: PeeHaa@php.net\r\nHeader: Injection \r\n";`

Comment: Deterring spam is a complex, non-trivial issue, and likely too broad for Stack Overflow. One of the most general approaches is using a Captcha to tell apart humans from bots. There are several solutions available, like http://www.phpcaptcha.org/. Another approach is rate limiting, i.e. limiting the number of submissions that can come from one IP address over a certain span of time. There are also spam detection services like http://akismet.com. Many web sites use it to filter out spam.

Comment: @PeeHaa I think I remember that PHP started filtering out that kind of attack at some point, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Nope. If you give it a string it will happily accept it as the headers param. Not sure how you would add multiple headers otherwise :)

Comment: @PeeHaa ahh you're right of course. What is getting filtered is multiple lines in `$to`, but not if you just put it in the header field.

Comment: Security is too broad for this site but general performance isn't. Please use `header('Location: http://www.fashionablefondants.co.uk/response.html');` instead of `$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.fashionablefondants.co.uk/response.html'); echo $homepage;`

Comment: @user2191572 I've now changed the code as recommended. Thank you all for your input.